# Unable to get an result with only an simple if not null with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `a`.`id`   AS `id`, 
       `a`.`info` AS `info`, 
       `a`.`type` AS `type`, 
       `a`.`disp` AS `disp`, 
       `a`.`emp`  AS `emp`, 
       `a`.`tel`  AS `tel`, 
       `a`.`img`  AS `img`, 
       `a`.`job`  AS `job` 
FROM ((`my_shop` `a` 
       LEFT JOIN `my_shop2` `b` 
           ON(( `a`.`id` = `b`.`my_shop_id` ))) 
       JOIN `my_shop3` `c` 
           ON(( Ifnull(`b`.`my_shop_id`, `a`.`id`) = `c`.`id` )))
```

I've added a field in my_shop table called "personal_id". And what I want to do is to  get the above information if the personal_id field contains an id. How will I achieve this ? Some example or tips would be great! I would love to hear from you!

Comment: did you getting any error ?

Comment: The `personal_id` field appears nowhere in your query.  Please add sample data and your expected result.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to add the "personal_id" condition to the following code to the current query, since I'm a total beginner.

Comment: add where condition like this select `a`.`id` AS `id`,
       `a`.`info` AS `info`,
    `a`.`type` AS `type`,
    `a`.`disp` AS `disp`,
    `a`.`emp` AS `emp`,
    `a`.`tel` AS `tel`,
    `a`.`img` AS `img`,
    `a`.`job` AS `job` 
from `my_shop` `a` left join `my_shop2` `b` on(`a`.`id` = `b`.`my_shop_id`)
join `my_shop3` `c` on(ifnull(`b`.`my_shop_id`,`a`.`id`) = `c`.`id`)  where `a`.`personal_id`=X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below mentioned code which will solve your issue.

```
SELECT 
    a.id   AS id, 
    a.info AS info, 
    a.type AS type, 
    a.disp AS disp, 
    a.emp  AS emp, 
    a.tel  AS tel, 
    a.img  AS img, 
    a.job  AS job 
FROM my_shop a 
LEFT JOIN my_shop2 b ON a.id = b.my_shop_id 
INNER JOIN my_shop3 c ON Ifnull(b.my_shop_id, a.id) = c.id
WHERE a.personal_id IS NOT NULL;
```

and if you want to compare `personal_id` with specific table column value than use below where command

```
WHERE a.personal_id = <tablename.column_name>
```

Try this and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

If you want `JOIN` personal_id with my_shop3, use below

```
SELECT a.id AS id, 
       a.info AS info, 
       a.type AS type, 
       a.disp AS disp, 
       a.emp  AS emp, 
       a.tel  AS tel, 
       a.img  AS img, 
       a.job  AS job 
FROM my_shop a  LEFT JOIN my_shop2 b ON a.id = b.my_shop_id 
       JOIN my_shop3 c ON Ifnull(b.my_shop_id, a.id) = c.id  AND a.personal_id = C.id
```

If you want use personal_id with `WHERE` clause, use below

```
SELECT a.id AS id, 
       a.info AS info, 
       a.type AS type, 
       a.disp AS disp, 
       a.emp  AS emp, 
       a.tel  AS tel, 
       a.img  AS img, 
       a.job  AS job 
FROM my_shop a  LEFT JOIN my_shop2 b ON a.id = b.my_shop_id 
       JOIN my_shop3 c ON Ifnull(b.my_shop_id, a.id) = c.id  
WHERE a.personal_id = <id value>
```